# Как циклом выполнять задачи в asyncio.gather

Tags: python, async-await, for

так ребята, смотрите вот есть у меня значит список из стрингсессий sessions = ["первая сессия", "вторая"] и т.д ну вы поняли. лежит у меня этот список в моем бд.
У меня есть деф который принимает эти сессии и выполняет за них определенные действия. такие как отправка сообщения и т.д
Что же мне нужно так это цикл в asyncio.gather
Ну если с примером то чтобы выглядело как-то так:

```
async def main():
await asyncio.gather(
    (work(ClientFunc(i, 543523, "hahafgdsa"))) for i in session)
)
```

имею ввиду чтобы не выглядело а функционал был похожим по смыслу. думаю понятно что вот такой замудрённый цикл не пашет.
выбивает ошибку:

```
RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: <coroutine object work at 0x0000010E4C9B05C0>
```

внимание знатоки вопрос:
Как оставить асинхронное выполнение функции но так чтобы эти функции я мог вставлять циклом

Чтобы не выглядело вот так:

```
async def main():
await asyncio.gather(
    work(ClientFunc("session1", 543523, "hahafgdsa"))),
    work(ClientFunc("session2", 543523, "hahafgdsa"))),
    work(ClientFunc("session3", 543523, "hahafgdsa"))),
    work(ClientFunc("session4", 543523, "hahafgdsa")))...
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А так тоже не работает ?

```
await asyncio.gather(
    *[work(ClientFunc(i, 543523, "hahafgdsa"))) for i in session]
)
```

Comment: а вот это уже работает, ты гений спс